# Bootsrap Dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, dropdown

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src ="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" >Article <span class = "caret"></span></button>
    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">Technology</a>s</li>
        <li><a href="#">Scienece</a>s</li>
        <li><a href="#">Scienece</a>s</li> 
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a problem with the bootstrap in this code, but i am not able to figure it out, plase help me

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: <li><a href="#">Scienece</a>s</li> What is the S for?, shouldn't it be just  <li><a href="#">Scienece</a></li>.

Comment: sorry my bad, yes ur correct, but the code dropdown menu isnt working still

Comment: The dropdown menu is not working. When i press the button, the options --> Technology and Scienec are not appearing

Answer (score 0):

now its working , http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/xkL15guj/24/

You can use **Bootstrap CDN**

```
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your added files are not working properly. (css and js files) 
You can use/try with external links while developing.

This works;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" >Article <span class = "caret"></span></button>
    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">Technology</a>s</li>
        <li><a href="#">Scienece</a>s</li>
        <li><a href="#">Scienece</a>s</li> 
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```